# Typescript and ienumerators

Tags: typescript, ienumerable, ienumerator

Is this real to return ienumerators in typescript methods?
I have installed typescript-dotnet libs. One of my classes implements IList<> and IEnumerable<> so I have to implement getEnumerator() method which returns IEnumerator<>
I guess that I should use yield for this purpose but not really understand how to make it on proper way

Comment: What are you trying to do? You should probably just use arrays.

Comment: Just want to how to implement this method (if it's possible)

Answer (score -1):

I've found very useful infromation in github sources
[here](https://github.com/electricessence/TypeScript.NET)